# Uncaught PDOException in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error when I try to run my PHP with my database

> **Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)** in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Barter Trade\config.php:7 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Barter Trade\config.php(7):
> **PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '')** #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Barter Trade\registration.php(2):
> require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Barter Trade\config.php on line 7

Comment: `using password; NO` means you left out the password when connecting to the database.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please remember check it as answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The message is clearly:

> (using password: NO)

Your database requires password and you are not sending one.